# Openshift nodejs app doesn't work for sending contact form to email

Tags: openshift

This works locally for me but each time I push to openshift and test, I get the same error message in the form:

"Message could not be delivered, please check your Internet connection!"

Which of course I added in Express when the mail server fails to send the content of the html form.

Is this a setting that I need to do in openshift in order for my nodejs app to have a working contact me page?

my website is:

http://nodejs-damasco.rhcloud.com/feedback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some feedback from Redhat, I decided to give SendGrid a try and experiment. It was super easy to set up and emails arrive quick, plus they offer a free service.

Check it out here:

https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-nodejs

I will pack the website once am done and share it as open source project in Github.